# Recursive objects causing stackoverflow on StackService.Redis client method Store()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nosql, redis, servicestack

I have two POCO classes (Account and Invoice) and as you can see (below are mockups of these classes) they are recursive.

When I pass in an invoice object with the account property set and then try to store it using the redis client  it causes a stackoverlow due to recursion.  Below is an example of how I'm making the call.

```
CachingService.Store<Invoice>(invoiceObj);


public class CachingService {
    // ....
    public static void Store<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (var client = _redisClientsManager.GetClient())
        {   
            var typedClient = client.GetTypedClient<T>();
            typedClient.Store(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Example of my POCO classes:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public bool IsActive { set; get; }

    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { set; get; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public bool IsPaid { set; get; }
    public DateTime? LastSent { set; get; }
    public int AccountId { set; get; }

    public virtual Account Account { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: I should note that when I change ICollection to IEnumerable the issue goes away.  Perhaps there is an actual fix to this issue other than changing the property type.

Comment: Can you provide the methods you use to create this recursion? I can't see it happening in the code you've provided.

Comment: Seems like is it Redis Serializer issue.

Comment: Hi Simon, the invoiceObj contains an Account object.  If you really need a code snippet I can provide one but that is all that is in the invoiceObj in this instance.  Like Oleskii said, I also think its the Redis Seralizer.  Is there a way to flag a property to be ignored by the serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most serializers ([ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) included) does not support cyclical references. This is a major anti-pattern when designing DTOs.

To resolve this, you want to tell [ServiceStack.Text's serializers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) to ignore that property for Serialization which you can do using the [IgnoreDataMember] property or changing it so it's not a public property or change it into a method.

Comment: [IgnoreDataMember] was the attribute I was looking for.  Thanks!